# Use R code in outsystems application

Tags: r, connect, integrate, outsystems

My question is as stated above: is it possible to use R code in an outsystems application? To connect the code to the application as an action or something?

I had a basic course in outsystems, and I like how it works. Especially how easy it is for other people to use the application. Now I want to use it on something I created in R. Or, in other words, create a nice app around the functionalities of my code in R.

Answer (score 1):

Extensibility in OutSystems is done via [Extensions](https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/10/Extensibility_and_Integration/Extend_Logic_with_Your_Own_Code/Extensions). The extensions can be written in Java or C#. So an option you could try is to use .Net wrappers that access the R code and integrate that with OutSystems. One example like that is [R.Net](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet).

Comment: Whether you can write Java or C# extensions depends on the stack of Outsystems you use. Most common is the .NET stack which supports C# code of course. I also heard that Outsystems have the wish to get rid of the Java stack in the future.